# $ABC$ is an equilateral $\triangle $ of side $24$cm. If the centroid $O$ is the centre of the circle then find the radius of the circle.

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

$ABC$ is an equilateral $\triangle $ of side $24$cm. If the centroid $O$ is the centre of the circle then find the radius of the circle.

I couldn't get any idea to solve. How can I approach such type of problems?

Comment: Easy one. If you want to solve geometry problems, you grab a textbook about geometry. Elementary problems like yours are explained in nauseating detail, there.

Comment: @AnanthKamath, $O$, the centroid of triangle, is the centre of the circle.

Comment: Does the SO complies with the US KAPPA act? Children under 13, should not be able to create online accounts and that question looks well underage mathematics(under 6th grade)

Comment: @bedbad,  This is not a 6th grade question. A sixth grader wouldn't know the meaning of 'centroid' of triangle.

Comment: I didn't study in US school in 6th grade. But in my school we solved these question in 3d grade, more advanced in 5th(no 4th) and finished by 6th grade and it was well before the age of 13.

Comment: The question is perfectly clear - (lookup the word centroid)

Comment: @bedbad, I don't know which country you belong to. But courses differ from country to country.

Comment: Can you provide the source of the question - textbook, please? If you are from Indian school this is an underage question for sure

Comment: @ AnanthKamath, I couldn't understand what is unclear in the question for you?

Comment: In this case you can sue the site for 16k$ dollars(i'm sorry SO, but it's true) if you didn't lie about your age and didnt send SO explicit parental permission

Comment: @bedbad, This question doesn't have a definite source. It was asked in class 9th exam.

Comment: I'm not confronting you, but if you are above age of 12-13 it is in everybody's interest to clearly know this. I was just 12 in 9th grade. If you are that age right now you need to say it.

Comment: @bedbad, I am obviously over 13 years and I hope that there is no issue if I want to learn it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58828/discussion-between-bedbad-and-aryabhatta).

Comment: What circle? It touches the sides of the triangle or passes through the vertices or anything else?

Comment: Look up Euclidian Geometry axiom set then and learn by heart. Then you can derive theorem without graphics. Then you can confirm it with graphics. The question is absolutely no brainer - but it's a bad practice to struggle with each such question separately - there are zilliards of them and the only actual way to learn is from bottom to the top.

Comment: If you are adolescent you can learn whole Euclidean geometry in 2 days this way. There is no point to solve it kids way or even with basic trigonometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the equilateral triangle $ABC$, construct the medians $AD$, $BE$, $CF$. (See figure on the page [Properties of Equilateral Triangles](http://brilliant.org/wiki/properties-of-equilateral-triangles/).) We know the following important properties of an equilateral triangle:

- The medians are also altitudes, angle bisectors, and perpendicular bisectors of sides.
- The medians intersect at the point $O$ which is simultaneously the centroid, orthocenter, incenter, and circumcenter.

Note that in the right triangle $BOD$ we have 
$$BD={BC\over2}=12, \quad \angle BOD=60^\circ, \quad \angle DBO=30^\circ.$$
Hence, using the trigonometric functions tan and cos, we find
$$
\mbox{ the radius of inscribed circle (inradius) } DO = 
BD \tan 30^\circ = 4\sqrt3;
$$
$$
\mbox{ the radius of circumscribed circle (circumradius) } BO = 
{BD \over \cos30^\circ} = 8\sqrt3.
$$